# Fetching Date from Sqlite Database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Sqlite DataBase I saved date in a data type DATE. How can i fetch this date from cursor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQLite stores a string representing the current time in UTC (GMT), using the ISO8601 date/time format. This format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), is by the way suitable for date/time comparisons.

Use the below code to retrieve the date.

```
Cursor row = databaseHelper.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
COLUMN_INDEX}, ID_COLUMN_INDEX + "=" + rowId,
null, null, null, null, null);
String dateTime = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_INDEX));
```

This, returns a string, parse it and reformat to your local format and time zone:

```
DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
date = iso8601Format.parse(dateTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
}

long when = date.getTime();
int flags = 0;
flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME;
flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE;
flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;

String finalDateTime = android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateTime(context,
when + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(when), flags);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi Nagaraj436 I am using data type DATE for column date . So i can not use cursor.getString

Comment: @DeepakKataria Have you tried using the getString()? did you got any errors using that?

Comment: use datatype for date as string that would help u.i am doing the same. as said by @Nagaraj436 that helps for parsing the date in form that he mentioned and other forms as well.. make use of cursor.getString().toString()

Comment: @DeepakKataria is my answer helpful then up the answer.

Comment: iso8601Format would be "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 13):

SQLite does not really have a `DATE` type (the `DATE` keyword just means the column has a `NUMERIC` affinity, per [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)), so it's up to you to choose a convention for how you'll store dates. Common conventions are (a) to use real numbers to store Julian dates or (b) to use integer numbers to store a Unix epoch (seconds since 1970, which the SQLite date and time function support with the 'unixepoch' argument per [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)).

If you're doing storing dates as Unix epoch (convenient for Android since calling `.getTime()` on a `Date` object returns the number of milliseconds since 1970), then read the SQLite `DATE` field as a `long` and pass the millisecond equivalent of that into the `java.util.Date` constructor `Date(long milliseconds)`. So, it would look something like this:

```
SQLiteManager dbManager = new SQLiteManager(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
    new String[] { COLUMN_NAME_ID, COLUMN_NAME_DATE },
    null, null, // selection, selectionArgs
    null, null, null, null); // groupBy, having, orderBy, limit
try {
    while(cursor.moveNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        // Read the SQLite DATE as a long and construct a Java Date with it.
        Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(1)*1000);
        // ...
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred way of using Dates in SQLite and Android.

Comment: Nice but i'm a little bit confused.. The type of field on SQLite in this case should be DATETIME or INT or DATE?

Answer (score 4):

this code works

```
String s= cursor.getString(position);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d=new Date();
    try {
         d=  dateFormat.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    YourObject.setDate(d);
```

Comment: perfect code but need  to modify to set to view according to their requirement.Ex:date to add  **textView**. **textview.setText(dateformate.formate(d))**